# JPA entity modified by reflection not merged by entity manager

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, wildfly-15

I need to check if my actual entity is different from the old one.

I use reflection because my method must be standardized.

For each column, I update the value if and only if it's not null (because i read it from a CSV and a column may be not specified).

```
for(Field column : fields){
   column.setAccessible(true);
   Object newValue = column.get(myObject);
   if( newValue != null && !newValue.equals(column.get(oldObject))){
      column.set(oldObject, newValue);
   }
}

this.entitymanager.merge(oldObject)
```

If I do the changes like that, no UPDATE query is done.

If I change the value in the normal way `oldobject.setValue(newValue)` the query is done and the record is updated.

Why no UPDATE query is done by the entity manager if I change value via reflection?

Comment: I think it's because managed entities are proxy-ed and the setter invocation would do what you need. I'm not sure if this is possible the way you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Just find some good information about such behaviour at [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/126802/) :

> By default when using weaving/agent EclipseLink uses attribute change
>   tracking to detect changes. This will not detect changes made through
>   reflective field access (method access is ok though).
>
> You can change the default using the @ChangeTracking annotation to
>   deferred which will detect change made through reflection. i.e.
>   @ChangeTracking(ChangeTrackingType.DEFERRED)
>
> You could also disable weaving, or weaving of change tracking in the 
>   persistence.xml using, "eclipselink.weaving.changetracking"="false"

So there are couple of solutions that can try :

1. Use reflective method access
2. [Change the ChangeTracking to deferred or even disable it](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_changetracking.htm)
3. [Disable weaving](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/solutions/testingjpa004.htm#sthref142)

Comment: Thank you. I'm testing the first solution

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @Ken Chan answer, I correct the method using getters and setters.

```
for(Field column : columns){
   Method mSet = myclass.getMethod("set"+ StringUtils.capitalize(column.getName()), column.getType());
   Method mGet = myclass.getMethod("get"+ StringUtils.capitalize(column.getName()));
   Object newValue = mGet.invoke(articolo);
   if( newValue != null && !newValue.equals(mGet.invoke(old))){
        mSet.invoke(old, newValue);
   }
 }
```

I must pay attention to methods' name. If entity have the property `description`, there must be also `getDescription()` and `setDescription()`.

Now it works